# ¿Cómo importar multiples archivos csv en R Studio?

Tags: r, rstudio

Quisiera importar múltiples archivos csv si tener que realizarlo por "import datset", ya que son aproximadamente 150.

He intentado el siguiente código:

```
files2010 <- list.files(path="C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/R/Media movil/", pattern="*.csv")

myfiles<-lapply(files2010, read.delim)
```

Pero me sale el siguiente error

> Error in file(file, "rt") : no se puede abrir la conexión Además:
>   Warning message: In file(file, "rt") :   no fue posible abrir el
>   archivo 'MOVILING_Aeropuerto.csv': No such file or directory

También intenté con lo siguiente:

```
Mediamovil2010<-do.call(rbind, lapply(files2010, function(x) as.data.frame(fread(x,header = TRUE))))
```

Pero me sale el mismo mensaje de error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dado que obtienes los nombres de los archivos con `list.files` entonces el archivo existe. Lo más seguro es que tu directorio de trabajo en R no sea el mismo en el que se encuentran los archivos, puedes checarlo corriendo  `getwd()` en R. Si es igual a "C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/R/Media movil/" entonces puedes tener  algún problema de permisos para leer. Pero si no es igual puedes solucionarlo de varias maneras. Las que ahora tengo en mentes son

1- Fijar el directorio de trabajo en el mismo lugar donde están los archivos

```
setwd("C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/R/Media movil/")    
myfiles<-lapply(files2010, read.delim)
```

2- Usar `paste0` para pegar el directorio de trabajo fijo a los archivos

```
myfiles<-lapply(files2010, function(x){    
 read.delim(paste0("C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/R/Media movil/",x))    
})

#Usando la función read_csv
myfiles<-lapply(files2010, function(x){    
 read_csv(paste0("C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/R/Media movil/",x),  col_types = cols(Media movil PM10 = col_number(), PM10 = col_number(), PM2.5 = col_number(),  Year = col_number(), date = col_character()))     
})
```

Comment: ¡Hola Rolando! Muchas Gracias, ya me ha funcionado, sin embargo quisiera saber cómo puedo hacer para que me importe los documentos con las siguientes características: 
` ` ` 
MOVILING_Alcatraces <- read_csv("MOVILING_Alcatraces.csv", 
+     col_types = cols(`Media movil PM10` = col_number(), 
+         PM10 = col_number(), PM2.5 = col_number(), 
+         Year = col_number(), date = col_character()))
`` `

Comment: Lo más adecuado seria usar algo como en el punto 2. Pasar a la función anónima de `lapply` el nombre del archivo con el parámetro `x`, sustituir la funcion `read.delim` por `read_csv` y además del nombre dentro de `paste0` pasar el parametro `col_types` como en tu comentario. Sólo ten cuidado de que todos los archivos tengan las mismas columnas.

Comment: Gracias Rolando, pero no he podido realizarlo aún, todos los archivos tienen exactamente las mismas columnas. Estoy un poco confundida en la introducción del parámetro `col_types` dentro de `paste0`

Comment: Laura, creo que no me di a entender bien. Sólo el nombre va dentro de paste0. Edite la respuesta agregando lo que quise describir en el comentario anterior.